# Minified jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<img id="imgHelp" src="Images/Icons/Help16.png" alt="help" style="float:right;" />
<div id="hlpCalculator" class="tooltip" style="display:none;">
  <ol>
    <h3>How to use this help</h3>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li> 
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Uh! to make me stay, click on the help once.</li>
    <li>Click me if you had enough.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<script>
    var showCalcHelp = function () { $("#hlpCalculator").slideDown(30); };
    var hideCalcHelp = function () { $("#hlpCalculator").slideUp(300); };

    $("#imgHelp").bind('mouseenter', showCalcHelp);
    $("#imgHelp").bind('mouseleave', hideCalcHelp);

    $("#imgHelp").bind('click', function () {
        $("#imgHelp").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
        $("#hlpCalculator").slideDown(30);
    }); 

    $("#hlpCalculator").click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp(300);
        $("#imgHelp").bind('mouseenter', showCalcHelp);
        $("#imgHelp").bind('mouseleave', hideCalcHelp);
});
```

The above code works fine. For the sake of 'minified', can anyone suggest the shortest way for the script part, something like..

```
$("#imgHelp").hover(function(){...},function(){...}).click(function(){...});
```

There are conflicts between hover and click though.

TIA.

Comment: Oops, I'll format this properly in an answer.

Comment: Instead of "minifying", why not just write "pretty code" with "removed redundancies"? (GZIP is *really good* at minifying.)

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7 `.on()` and `off` are preferred methods  for event binding and unbinding. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
<script>
    var showCalcHelp = function () { $("#hlpCalculator").slideDown(30); };
    var hideCalcHelp = function () { $("#hlpCalculator").slideUp(300); };

    $("#imgHelp").on({'mouseenter' : showCalcHelp, 'mouseleave': hideCalcHelp});


    $("#imgHelp").on('click', function () {
        $("#imgHelp").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $("#hlpCalculator").slideDown(30);
    }); 

    $("#hlpCalculator").click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp(300);
    $("#imgHelp").bind({'mouseenter' : showCalcHelp, 'mouseleave': hideCalcHelp});
});
```

As mrtsherman suggested what you want is method chaining for shortening the code, minification is different matter altogether. It not only shortens the code to a great extent but obfuscates it and makes it unreadable. See closure-compiler.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

I'll format this as an answer, although it's really a compilation of comments on the previous answers.

First: Favor clear code over very clever code. As @pst said, GZIP is great at making things smaller than they are. Chaining, as @mrtsherman suggests, is the way to have jQuery traverse the DOM once per element you're finding.

Second: Consider the lifespan before you start worrying about its size and efficiency. Code with a short lifespan, as you find in many jQuery-enhanced Web "pages" really doesn't have to squeeze cycles. Frameworks as their codepaths can be frequently used.

Third: Remember that browsers normally cache as much as possible, so even if your code is pretty big, it's likely to be a one-time hit.

I'm not making excuses for writing sloppy code; rather, I'm suggesting that writing exceptionally clear beautiful code will allow you to add features because your intent is so obviously expressed in your code. People will almost certainly appreciate the extra functionality than the dozen bytes you saved.